# Barchart for data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, bar-chart

I have the data in the below table in excel and I want to display it in a bar chart where each row will be a bar but each two rows will be two bars sticked together representing Gas and Electric, so for example the first two adjacent bars will be representing the first two rows WH and then there will be a space and then another two adjacent bars representing third and fourth rows SE and so on

[image]

The result will be something like this but with each two bars adjacent to each together as shown below highlighted with arrows and have the bars properly labeled with the corresponding type (WH, SR or MH) and Gas or Electric.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Insert empty rows in the table every two rows. And insert a space in the first cell of each empty row (this is to avoid a small formatting issue with the column labels)

[image]

2. Right click on one of the bars and choose "Format Data Series" from the pop up menu

[image]

3. Set the Gap Width to 0%

[image]

Final result should look like this:

[image]